# setState not working when refactoring to import components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I have a set of data on a page that I'm trying to update based on a user clicking a pills for a team name. Each pills sets state to the team name clicked. Everything worked when it was on one page, but I'm trying to reduce the complexity and refactor it a bit, but I'm struggling with state across components.

Thanks for your help!

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import FilterBox from 'components/filters/FilterBox';
import ToolCard from 'components/Card';
import ToolInfo from './ToolInfo';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      teamName: null,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const filters = this.state;
    const filteredTools = ToolInfo.filter(
      (tool) => {
        return (filters.teamName === null || tool.teamName === filters.teamName);
      },
    );

    return (
      <FilterBox />

      {filteredTools.map((block) => ToolCard(block))}

    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

FilterBox.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { TeamFilters } from 'components/filters/Filters';
import SingleFilter from './SingleFilter';

class FilterBox extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      teamName: null,
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
       {TeamFilters.map((data) => (
         <SingleFilter
           data={data}
           onClick={() => {
             this.setState({ teamName: data.teamStateName });
             });
           }}
         />
       ))}
    );
  }
}

export default FilterBox;
```

SingleFilter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

const SingleFilter = ({ data, onClick }) => (
  <Nav.Item className='mr-1 mt-1' key={data.teamDisplayName}>
    <Nav.Link eventKey={data.teamDisplayName} onClick={onClick}>
      {data.teamDisplayName}
    </Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
);

export default SingleFilter;
```

ToolCard.js

```
import React from 'react';

function ToolCard(props) {
  const tool = props;

  return (
    <Card with all of the tool info in it.. like..>
       {tool.title}
       {tool.description}
        etc
    <Card/>
  );
}

export default ToolCard;
```

TeamFilters.js

```
const TeamFilters = [   
  {   
    teamStateName: null,  
    teamDisplayName: 'All',  
  }, {   
    teamStateName: 'Accounting',  
    teamDisplayName: 'Accounting',  
  }, {   
    teamStateName: 'Data',  
    teamDisplayName: 'Data',  
  }, {
    teamStateName: '',  
    teamDisplayName: 'Other',  
  },  
];   

export default TeamFilters;
```

ToolInfo.js

```
const ToolInfo = [
  {
    title: 'Concur',
    description: 'Expense management',
    webUrl: 'example.com',
    teamName: 'Accounting',
  }, {
    title: 'BigQuery',
    description: 'Run Queries',
    webUrl: 'example.com',
    teamName: 'Data',
  }, {
    title: 'Toolio',
    description: 'Some misc tool',
    webUrl: 'example.com',
    teamName: '',
  },
];

export default ToolInfo;
```

Comment: do you want to have a latest `teamName` in your state of index.js?I with FilterBox and SingleFilter, it works without any critical flaws(I've copied yours and ran on my env)

Comment: you haven't used `teamName` anywhere. just initialized and setted it once.

Comment: @msc I just updated the code to be a bit more expansive to show how I'm putting content on the main dashboard page. So right now the example I've given will show the page exactly as it was before when it was working, and clicking the filters doesn't break anything, but it also doesn't set the state so that the main index.js will update the content shown.

Comment: @JaydeepGalani I updated it a bit so you can see why teamName is relevant.

Comment: So on load Concur, BigQuery, and Toolio should load. If you click the "Data" team filter, only Big Query should show. If you go back to "All", teamName should be set back to null and all should show again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main state is in index.js, but you are changing state in FilterBox where you have not used it.,

So what you can do is remove state from FilterBox, and call a parent function same as onClick in FilterBox again.

see this,

FilterBox,

```
<SingleFilter
           data={data}
           onClick={() => {
             this.props.onClick(data.teamStateName);
           }}
/>
```

index.js

```
<FilterBox 
   onClick={(teamName) => {
      this.setState({ teamName });
   }}
/>
```

Hope you got it. please ignore any code typo.

Comment: Yep! This was it. Sorry for the newbie question.. react is new to me and this whole passing state thing is still racking my brain!

Comment: Everyone is newbie here, Happy Coding.